# Почему запрос возвращает все записи, если использовать IN вместо = в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT customer, SUM(price)
FROM tab GROUP BY customer 
HAVING SUM(price) IN (SELECT max(sm) FROM ( SELECT sum(price) AS sm FROM tab GROUP by customer ) AS t);
```

Почему такой [запрос](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b682bd/2/0) возвращает все записи, но если использовать `=` вместо `IN`, то все работает корректно?

Так же, если отдельыно выполнить `SELECT max(sm) FROM ( SELECT sum(price) AS sm FROM tab GROUP by customer ) AS t` и вставить результат в первоначальный запрос, то все будет корректно.

Comment: Хм. с виду такого быть не должно. не могли бы вы привести тестовую таблицу с данными на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com

Comment: проверил на похожей таблице у себя `=` и `IN` возвращают одинаковый результат

Comment: @Mike, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b682bd/2/0

Comment: Мистика ... Если в запрос в IN добавить `union all select 0` то все становится нормально ...

Comment: @Mike, еще заметил, что на sqlfiddle.com, если выбрать версию 5.5, то все нормально, начиная с версии 5.6 - странное поведение

Comment: @Jean-Claude Да, там на выходе одно значение, но запрос реально возвращает строки со всеми значениями, а не только с тем, что дает IN ...

Comment: `HAVING sum(price)+0 IN...` так же дает верный результат ... и `select price, sum(price) as ss .... having ss IN...` то же верный

Comment: Похожая проблема на багтрекере MySQL https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34874 в качестве решения проблемы рекомендуют использовать `=` :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ основан на комментарии пользователя @Mike.

Судя по багтрекеру MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34874 – это баг, обнаруженный в 2008 году. Он до сих пор не исправлен. Проблемные версии MySQL: `5.0+`

**В качестве решения** предлагается использовать оператор `=` вместо `IN`.